# Mutable tree like data structure (group by year-month-day)

Tags: rust

I have a list of pictures which I want to group by year-month-day.

After getting the information from the disk, I first store them in a Vec with the following data structure:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct PictureInformation {
    title: String,
    date: chrono::NaiveDate
}
```

I now want to create a tree with the following structure: Vec of Years, each year can contain months, and each month can contain days, and each day has several PictureInformation.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Year {
    year: i32,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Month {
    year: i32,
    month: u8
}
```

My way to group them is currently relatively simple:

- For each PictureInformation in Vec:

  - Extract the year
  - Is year already present in grouped data structure?
  - if not, create a new `Year` and add it to the data structure and continue with that one
  - if yes, use the one returned from the data structure.
  - Continue same thing for month and day.

My first approach was using a Vec, with a contained `Box<Year>` because the Vec can change it's position during resize and the reference which I would have to year would no longer be valid. So I thought about holding a reference to the `Year` inside the box. Unfortunately I have problems with the borrow checker, i.e. that I cannot get a reference to `Year` because the data is owned by the vector after I've moved it there.

My second approach was using a HashSet, but the contents of a HashSet are not mutable. I've implemented `Hash` only for the `year` attribute, but I could not get a mutable `Year` out of the Hashset (although I really liked `get_or_insert()`).

My third approach was to insert a RefCell inside the HashSet, but it does not implement `Hash`.

Then I've tried `indextree::Arena`, but it seems it can only contain the same data types.

How can I achieve this? Or should I approach this a complete other way? 
Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a `HashMap<i32, HashMap<i32, HashMap<i32, Vec<Picture>>>>`? With the proper type aliases for readability of course.

Comment: Or with `BTreeMap` if you want to keep them sorted…

Comment: Thanks, this was actually really easy and solved my issue :)